# How to find occurrences of a string in one table and display the result in another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

Table 1: `Destination` Columns (`DesId`,`DestinationName`)

Table 2: `TravelDetails` Columns (`TravelId`,`DesID`,`DestinationSelected`)

I want to find the number of occurrences of different `DestiantionSelected` (in Table 2) and want to display the result in another table (Table 3)

Table 3 `blueprint`:

```
Destination       |Occurences

Maldives            |3

Australia |2
```

Comment: Provide structures as CREATE TABLE, not as approximate description. Provide some sample data (3-5 rows per table) as INSERT INTO scripts. Show desired output for this data. And **select only one DBMS** by removing excess tag.

Comment: So you need to join the 2 table and use count and group by. Do you already to try this way?